# Passing an image through PHP

Tags: php

I am using the following code trying to pass an image through my script, however all that happens is an html file gets downloaded instead.

This is a script for email tracking, at first I am updating a DB, then I actually move on to passing the image which is where I get the problem.

The html file that downloads, contains the following text ``` GIF89a€ÿÿÿ!ÿXMP DataXMP ÿþýüûúùø÷öõôóòñðïîíìëêéèçæåäãâáàßÞÝÜÛÚÙØ×ÖÕÔÓÒÑÐÏÎÍÌËÊÉÈÇÆÅÄÃÂÁÀ¿¾½¼»º¹¸·¶µ´``³²±°¯®­¬«ª©¨§¦¥¤£¢¡ Ÿžœ›š™˜—–•”“’‘ŽŒ‹Š‰ˆ‡†…„ƒ‚€~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba``_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"!   !ù,D; ```

This is my PHP

```
$graphic_http = 'blank.gif';
$filesize = filesize( 'blank.gif' );

    header( 'Pragma: public' );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: private',false );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.gif"' );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
    header( 'Content-Length: '.$filesize );
    readfile( $graphic_http );
```

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not telling the browser what the file type is so it's not handling it as a GIF image, but as text.

Include the following line:

`header ("Content-Type: image/gif");`

//Edit
To prevent the file from being downloaded and simply opened in the browser, remove the line:
`header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.gif"' );`

This is what tells the browser to download the file rather than simply show it.

Comment: Okay, that helped. But it is still force downloading it...is there anyway to prevent that?

Comment: @Boris - Edited answer with the solution to that problem.

Comment: This is a correct answer :) My answer is identically xD

Answer (score 2):

You need to put content-type, and if is for showing and not for download, you need to remove content-attachment:

```
header( 'Pragma: public' );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: private',false );
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
// header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.gif"' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header( 'Content-Length: '.$filesize );
readfile( $graphic_http );
```